# "Never + past simple" vs "did not+ verb1" for denials

Tags: grammar, grammar-myths

I have a question related to the usage of '**never**'. I have heard native speakers use '**never**' when they want to negate something emphatically. And they use '**never**' instead of **"did not verb1"** to negate.

Here are a couple of example sentences:

> **Me**: Hey john, did you told Shyam that you dislike me? 
> **John**: It's a lie. I **never said/did not say** that.

To me **"did not say"** is more grammatically correct but I often hear native speakers use '**never**' in this kind of context. I would not use "**present perfect tense"** in the context as I was referring a specific event in the past.

- I **never went/did not go** to Australia when I was a child but after getting a job I went there last year.

I think both forms can be used in the above context.

- I **never was a/was not** a good student when I was in school but I was good at drawing.

I think the "**never was**" is more emphatic but both forms can be used. Can I use **never** instead of **"did not verb1"**  when I want to negate specific events in past emphatically? **Native speakers**, I want your opinions.

Comment: They're both grammatically correct; there isn't one that's "more grammatically correct" than the other.

Comment: I learned this rule: With "never", you usually use the present perfect. So it should be "It's a lie. I've never said that." It does however sound unnatural to me; I think here's an exception to that rule.

Comment: Please note that "did you told" in your example is not correct. You probably mean either "have you told" or "did you tell".

Comment: @Cacambo I've never heard that rule. Both "I have never done that" and "I never did that" are correct.

Answer (score 1):

*I never said that* is perfectly normal for the literal case: "there is no occasion in the past when I ever said that". In this use *I have never said that* is more likely, unless the reference is to a time period that is now past. That sentence is rather unusual, but it can come up in an exchange like

> A. When we worked at XYZ, people used to say that my desk was always messy.
> B. I never said that.

But you are right that colloquially, *never* is often used for an emphatic denial of a single instance. In this sense, *I never said that* is an emphatic version of *I didn't say that*.

Answer (score 0):

Either one can be used in most cases, but sometimes one fits better to the situation than the other. To use your example, if you said **I never went to Australia when I was a child but after getting a job I went there last year**, this means that, quite simply, you have not been to the country. If you used instead **I did not go**, this may be interpreted with another context, for example, if you didn't *go* but were *taken* against your will, or maybe there was an opportunity to go that you didn't take, but now you did after getting a job.